# Rust: как использование переменной внутри шаблона регулярного выражения?

Tags: rust

Не могу добиться чтобы значение переменной можно было подставить в шаблон регулярного выражения.
Пример:

```
 let mut agent = r"\[main\]";
    if args.len() == 3{    
        let args_agent = &args[2].trim();
            
                agent = r"\[" + args_agent + "\]";  // здесь ошибка         
    }
       println!("{}", agent);
```

Тут можно вообще использовать конкатенацию или по другому это делается?

Comment: Конкатенацию можно выполнять только с типом String (почему это никто не написал за шесть дней?)

Comment: @andreymal, imho навязывание стандартов под силу только самым крупным компаниям вроде microsoft или apple

Comment: Да я уж сам допер. Спасибо.